# Swift: task {} before iOS 15?

Tags: swift, swiftui, task

I am following tutorials to understand SwiftUI, and specifically how to call an API when a view appears.

I saw this:

```
List(results, id: \.trackId) { item in
    ListRow(item)
}
.task {
    // perform API here
}
```

But as my app targets iOS 14, I get this error:

> 'task(priority:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer

So what could I do instead? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskEntry: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    // Add other properties if needed
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var results = [TaskEntry]()
    @State private var dataTask: Task<Void, Error>?
  
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            dataTask = Task {
                do {
                    results = try await loadData()
                } catch {
                    print("Error loading data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    // Handle error accordingly
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            dataTask?.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async throws -> [TaskEntry] {
        // Simulated asynchronous data fetching
        // Replace this with your actual data fetching logic
        
        // For now, returning an empty array as a placeholder
        return []
    }
}
```

**Edit the answer.**

Comment: This doesn't provide automatic cancelation, no?

Comment: now it can handle automatic cancelation when view will disappear

Answer (score 9):

You can write a version of `task { }` that works for iOS 13, iOS 14 and uses apple's version for iOS 15:

```
extension View {
    @available(iOS, deprecated: 15.0, message: "This extension is no longer necessary. Use API built into SDK")
    func task(priority: TaskPriority = .userInitiated, _ action: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Void) -> some View {
        self.onAppear {
            Task(priority: priority) {
                await action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I sometimes wonder, why apple couldn't do this shit...

Answer (score 6):

Just switching to `.onAppear` is not correct since it's missing the point of [Structured Concurrency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SX7u5l3CGA). Every time you create a `Task` yourself you should be suspicious, you are doing something out of the ordinary.

Granted, in this case we don't have available a "structured concurrency aware" lifecycle modifier, so we need to make our own with `Task` init, but that means **you need to be responsible of respecting structured concurrency!**

This means that getting a proper backwards compatible solution to work is a bit more code, since you want to handle cancellation properly. For that you need to use also `.onDisappear` and cancel the task that you started on `.onAppear`.

If you want to have it reusable you can make [a custom .task modifier](https://gist.github.com/alexito4/4a9a7c6e3dc447a4f762cf1cf7346b5e).

Answer (score 5):

`async await` is available for iOS 13+.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task

if you need to use an `async` call is wrap the call in `Task`

```
.onAppear(){
    Task{
        //Your async code here
        // await yourFuncHere()
    }
}
```

`.onAppear` is a bit un reliable so I might opt for an `init` of an `ObservableObject` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

None of the accepted answer OP's question well. To create a `.task` modifier that propagates back to <iOS15, you need to create a task and keep it around until the `.onDisappear` and cancel it. Here's the full code that will let you use `.task` on any iOS/macOS version (the top answer here doesn't handle canceling the task).

```swift
struct TaskModifier: ViewModifier {
    let priority: TaskPriority
    let action: @Sendable () async -> Void
    @State var task: Task<Void, Never>? = nil

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                if task != nil {
                    task?.cancel()
                }
                task = Task(priority: priority, operation: action)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                task?.cancel()
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    @available(iOS, deprecated: 15.0)
    func task(priority: TaskPriority = .userInitiated, _ action: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(TaskModifier(priority: priority, action: action))
    }
}
```

Then to use, use like the built-in `.task`:

```swift
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .task {
                await someAsyncFunc()
            }
    }
}
```